# Inconsistency in formulas while copying a worksheet to new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets (named 'Q4 Financial Condition' and 'Q4 Activites') in a workbook (named 'Financial Statement Generator'), and I need to copy the worksheets into a new workbook.

Worksheet 'Q4 Financial Condition' has one cell formula as `='Q4 Activities'!F37 - H56 - H57`

When I do a copy to new workbook, the formula changes to `='[Financial Statement Generator.xlsm]Q4 Activities'!F37 - H56 - H57`

Is there any other alternatives in excel where I can retain the formula as it is and copy the worksheet to the new workbook.

I am doing the copy sheets through macros-

```
Dim sheetName As Variant
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
sheetName = Array("Q" & Quarter & " Financial Condition", "Q" & Quarter & " Activities")
ThisWorkbook.sheets(sheetName(1)).Copy Before:=wb.sheets(1)
ThisWorkbook.sheets(sheetName(0)).Copy Before:=wb.sheets(1)
```

Comment: If it is one time do find `[Financial Statement Generator.xlsm]` and replace with empty string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the worksheets one at a time will have the issue you describe.  The simple way around it is to copy both sheets at once:

```
Dim sheetName As Variant
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
sheetName = Array("Q" & Quarter & " Financial Condition", "Q" & Quarter & " Activities")
ThisWorkbook.sheets(sheetName).Copy Before:=wb.sheets(1)
```